# How to detect if a point is located inside a range of points

Tags: opencv, image-processing

i have one main grayscale image and i divided it into inside-Activeregion and outside-ActiveRegion

the outSide-ActiveRegion is 3 pixels from the top,bottom,right,left. and the rest is the inside-Activeregion. let's assume i have the below image, and i want to detect if the 31.00001 x=2,y=0 is inside the active region according to my definition to the outSideActiveRegion

```
25.999985, 26.999994, 31.00001, 39.000046, 53.000084, 71.000038, 80.999962, 
78.999931, 71.999954;
23.999996, 26.000015, 32.000023, 45.000038, 64.000046, 76.000031, 76.000023, 
70.000015, 65.000023;
21.000031, 29.000027, 39.000027, 61.000008, 85.999985, 88.999992, 75.000023, 
64.000031, 63.000023;
26.000048, 39.000027, 53, 78.999962, 104.99993, 100.99995, 79, 67.000015,   
68.000023;
44.000015, 56.000004, 67.999992, 86.999969, 105.99995, 100.99998, 82.000023, 
74.000038, 77.000031;
66.999962, 73.999969, 78.999985, 86, 96.000023, 96.000038, 90.000053,   
90.000046, 94.000046;
79.999969, 83.999969, 85.999992, 87.000015, 92.000031, 102.00002, 112.00001,   
117.99999, 122.99999;
82.999985, 86.999985, 90.999992, 92.000008, 97.000031, 115.00001, 134.99995, 
142.99997, 148.99995;
82.000015, 85.000008, 93.999969, 100.99993, 109.9999, 128.99989, 148.99989,  
159.99988, 161.99989
```

**update**:

the inside-Activeregion is from 3,3 to ((width-1)-3),((height-1)-3). and the rest is the outSide-ActiveRegion

is there any functio in opencv that can detect if a certain point is inside a range of points?

Comment: Are your points forming a closed polygon? If so, you can use OpenCV's function [pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest) to get what you want.

Comment: @RogerRowland no they dont, the inside-Activeregion is from 3,3 to ((width-1)-3),((height-1)-3)

Comment: Then can you explain what you mean by *"inside a range of points"*? Perhaps give a simple example. From what you've said so far, it seems as simple as a "point-in-rectangle" test.

Comment: @RogerRowland yes, i want to know if a point is inside a rectangle or not

Comment: A diagram might help...

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to test if a point is in an axis-aligned rectangle is to first test if it is *not* inside:

```
bool PointInRect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int x, int y)
{
    if (x < left || x > right || y < top || y > bottom)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Or, as you're using OpenCV, you can create a suitable `cv::Rect` and use the `contains` method:

```
cv::Rect pRect(left, top, width, height);

cv::Point pPoint(x, y);

if (pRect.contains(pPoint))
{
    // do whatever ....
}
```

Comment: did u assume that, left=minimum y-coord top, minimum x-coord

Comment: @user2121 The general approach is that you test if the point is *outside* your left, right, top, bottom bounds. If it's *not* outside, then it *must* be inside. If your coordinate system treats x increasing from left to right and y increasing from top to bottom, then the example code I gave should be correct.

Comment: Why don't use just write  "return ! (x < left || x > right || y < top || y > bottom) "

Comment: @FooBar yes of course, I was just making the logic explicit.